# Android spinner, get selectedItem

Tags: java, android, spinner, onitemselectedlistener

As once I mentoined I am developing a "book an appointment" application. And in it, it have a spinner, where the user can select the place. 
In `BookAppointment.java` this is the spinner code:

```
public void addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection() {
    pspinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    pspinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new CustomOnItemSelectedListener());
}
```

The `CustomOnItemSelectedListener.java`:

```
public class CustomOnItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {
BookAppointment ba = new BookAppointment();
String place;
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id){
    Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(),
            "OnItemSelectedListener: " + parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString(),
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    place = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString(); //the actual selected item of spinner
    ba.setPlace(place);
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
}
```

And in `BookAppointment.java` I want to reach the selected item so I tried

```
public void setPlace(String place){
    this.place = place;
}
```

And in the `submit.onClick` there is a `BookApp(user, place, completeDate);`
And in debug mode somewhy in the onClick the `place` will be `null`. But even I change the `spinner`, the `setPlace` is run, and `this.place` will equal the original `place`, but after it somewhy `place` equals `null`. In `BookAppointment.java` there is a global `public String place;` and I nowhere else use place in BookAppointment.java . Please help me, what I missed? What I did wrong?

The onClick:

```
public void addListenerOnButton() {
    btnSubmitP = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSubmitP);
    pspinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    btnSubmitP.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            /*May I should place here the spinner's findViewById ?*/
            place = pspinner.getSelectedItem().toString(); //to get the actual selected place
            String completeDate = date + " " + itemValue;
            Toast.makeText(BookAppointment.this,
                    "OnClickListener : " +
                            "\nHelyszín: " + place + //it prints the actual selected item
                            "\nDátum: " + completeDate,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            User user = userLocalStore.getLoggedInUser();
            if (user == null) {
                Toast.makeText(BookAppointment.this,
                        "user = null",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            BookApp(user, place, completeDate); //Here the debug not display the place, nothin like place=null, nothing, only the user and completeDate's value
        }

    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this in submit.onClick:

```
String places= spinnerReferenceName.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

This should return you the selected string from spinner.

Comment: I tried but somewhy it works only when the activity starts. After any edit in spinner (like select another item) doesn't display, the `place` stays the original, first item :S.

Comment: I have put the place outside the onClick, now its inside, but somewhy the app is just jump over it, like that's never would be there O.o

Comment: Now, it works thanks! However debug jumps over the place, but in the `BookApp()` the place is right! I just should put the findviewbyid outside the onclick! Thank you!